# react-native dynamic activity indicator

Tags: react-native

I have multiple videos from an array map that each have an activity indicator. I want to set to false once the video is loaded.

Can someone please explain a method where I can do this for each video individually. At the moment on the onLoad callback it's just setting a global state value.

```
{revArray.map((camera,index) => (

<View key={'camera'+index} style={{backgroundColor:'#eeeeee'}}>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.removePrompt(camera.title.toString())}} style={{padding:6,position:'absolute',right:4,top:8,zIndex:999}}><Image source={require('../Images/delete1.png')} style={{width:16,height:16}}></Image></TouchableOpacity>

       <Text key={'title'+index} style={{color:'#113b92',textAlign:'center',padding:10,fontSize:16,fontFamily:'Lato-Bold'}}>{camera.title}</Text>

       <View style={{backgroundColor:'#000'}}>

       {this.state.isLoading ? ( <View style={{ position: 'absolute',left: 0,right: 0,top: 0,bottom: 0,alignItems: 'center',justifyContent: 'center',zIndex:9999}}>
       <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={'#000'} style={{backgroundColor:'#fff', padding:6, borderRadius:30}} /> 
      </View>
      ): (null)}

        <Video
        onLoad={()=>{this.setState({isLoading:false})}}
        key={'video'+index}
        ref={(ref: Video) => { this.video = ref }}
        style={styles.fullScreen}
        resizeMode='cover'
        source={{uri: camera.video+'?'+new Date()}}
        repeat={true}
      />
      </View>

      </View>

    ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `isLoading` is the state of the component rendering each of the videos in the array its only ever going to control all of them... What you want to do here is render a "container" component with its own state for each of these -

```
   class VideoWrapper extends React.Component {
      state = {
        isLoading: true
      }

      <View key={'camera'+index} style={{backgroundColor:'#eeeeee'}}>
      ...
          <Video
            onLoad={()=>{this.setState({isLoading:false})}}
            key={'video'+index}
            ref={(ref: Video) => { this.video = ref }}
            style={styles.fullScreen}
            resizeMode='cover'
            source={{uri: camera.video+'?'+new Date()}}
            repeat={true}
          />
     </View>
   }
```

And to render -

```
{revArray.map((camera,index) => 
  <VideoWrapper key={camera.id} camera={camera} index={index} />
)}
```

**This way each video in the array controls its own state.**

Comment: Nice one Maxwell ;) Sometimes you miss the obvious!